# Running StyleCopAnalyzers without building solution

Tags: c#, roslyn, stylecop, roslyn-code-analysis

I would like to use StyleCopAnalyzers https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers to find StyleCop violations in my code. However I can't find the way to run them without building entire solution. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [StyleCopTester](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/tree/master/StyleCop.Analyzers/StyleCopTester) project. That shows off a lot of the groundwork to run StyleCop Analyzers - and any other Roslyn Analyzer - using the Roslyn (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis) APIs.